# Wordpress - Suddenly Homepage Will Only Display Latest Posts

Tags: php, wordpress, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

My woocommerce store frontpage/homepage suddenly stopped displaying. It is a static page. Instead, no matter what I do the homepage will now only display latest posts. Although all other posts/pages on the site still work correctly. So far, the only way I can get the homepage to display a static page again is to change the permalink structure to default. The problem is I need the homepage to work with %postname% permalink structure, as it was up until yesterday.

I have made no theme updates or the adding of new plugins. I've only been manually adding product posts as drafts to expand my stores offered products. I suspect I must have tripped something that way somehow. For instance, I accidentally had 3 product post drafts with the same post ID, which I deleted, but maybe that tripped something...

So far I have:

- Went to settings>permalinks and pressed save.
- Set permalinks to default and then back to post name.
- Disabled most plugins one by one.
- Deleted .htaccess file so wp would generate a new one.
- Deleted contents of rewrite_rules field from wp_options in database.

Still I cannot get my homepage to display anything but latest posts unless I switch to default permalink structure. How can I fix this? I am out of my depth.

Comment: check setting >> reading and check option front page display.

Comment: hi, yes that was my first move